# Parse on the fly when running a query in MS Access

Tags: parsing, ms-access, join

In Microsoft Access, I have a query uniSelectedContacts and table possibles.

Let's say in possibles I have this:

```
Smith,John
Dough,John B
Ward,Jane Karon
Eggert,Samantha R
```

In uniSelectedContacts I have this:

```
Smith,John A 1552 1st Ave
Dough,John 1111 2st Ave
Ward,Jane K 2222 3st Ave
Eggert,Samantha Rachel 3333 1st Ave
```

I want to find where first and last name are identifiable. However, due to variation in middle initial, if there's no middle initial in possibles, then I want to account for all instances of the first and last name from uniSelectedContacts using INNER JOIN. If possibles has a middle initial(name), regardless of its middle initial or name, I want to account for the record(s) where first and last name of uniSelectedContacts and possibles are identical to each other and also where the first letter of middle initial(name) of uniSelectedContacts matches the first letter of middle initial(name) of possibles. So in the above example, this should be returned:

```
Smith,John 1552 1st Ave
Dough,John B 1111 2st Ave
Ward,Jane Karon 2222 3st Ave
Eggert,Samantha R 3333 1st Ave
```

The query below is fast and I want to preserve the speed, but 
it will skip all the above records (due to differences in middle initial(name):

```
SELECT possibles.fullname,
       uniSelectedContacts.addresses,
       uniSelectedContacts.cities,
       uniSelectedContacts.us_states_and_canada,
       uniSelectedContacts.zip_codes INTO PrepareForDuplicateCheck
  FROM uniSelectedContacts INNER JOIN possibles ON uniSelectedContacts.TheName = possibles.fullname;
```

To try to address the issue above, I have this:

```
SELECT possibles.fullname,
       uniSelectedContacts.addresses,
       uniSelectedContacts.cities,
       uniSelectedContacts.us_states_and_canada,
       uniSelectedContacts.zip_codes,
       possibles.[firstname] AS Expr1,
       possibles.[lastname] AS Expr2 INTO PrepareForDuplicateCheck
  FROM uniSelectedContacts INNER JOIN possibles ON uniSelectedContacts.TheName = possibles.fullname
  WHERE (((possibles.firstname)=Left([fullname],InStr([fullname],",")-1))
    AND ((possibles.lastname)=Mid([fullname],InStrRev([fullname],",")+1)));
```

The above gives "Enter Parameter Value possibles.firstname" message. But I'm also not sure if the underlying logic of the query will deliver the results I am expecting.

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little difficult to tell the fields (columns) from the posted samples, but I am assuming that both tables have a full name in the format surnameforename.

I am not suggesting that this will be fast, but try it.

```
SELECT p.aname, 
       u.addresses
       u.addresses, 
       u.cities,
       u.us_states_and_canada,
       u.zip_codes
INTO PrepareForDuplicateCheck
FROM (
      SELECT 
         Left([thename],IIf(InStrRev([thename]," ")>0,
           InStrRev([thename]," ")-1,Len([thename]))) As AName, 
         addresses, 
         cities,
         us_states_and_canada,
         zip_codes
      FROM uniSelectedContacts) u
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT 
         Left([fullname],IIf(InStrRev([fullname]," ")>0,
           InStrRev([fullname]," ")-1,Len([fullname]))) As AName 
      FROM possibles)  AS p 
ON u.AName = p.AName;
```

Another possibility:

```
SELECT p.aname, 
       u.addresses
INTO PrepareForDuplicateCheck
FROM  (
      SELECT 
         Left([fullname],IIf(InStrRev([fullname]," ")>0,
           InStrRev([fullname]," ")-1,Len([fullname]))) As AName 
      FROM possibles) p ,
           uniSelectedContacts u
WHERE  u.TheName Like p.AName & "*"
```

Comment: Thanks for response. After 40 minutes, I had to force quit the application as this query was still running. Is there any possible way to do a condition that will take no longer than 5 minutes? For example: if possibles middle initial is not present
then rip all middle initials from uniSelectedContacts and use inner join to return all matches by [last name],[first name]
otherwise
if possibles middle initial is present
then match it agaisnt uniSelectedContacts using inner join [last name],[first name] [middle initial].

Comment: How about running a "make table" to select all "easy" matches, followed by something similar to the above, excluding the contents of the "make table", as an append query ? Would that suit?

Comment: So if there's a total of 1 million records and if the easy matches return 200 records, then will the append query still have to run through 999,800 records?

Comment: Is it that bad? Does uniSelectedContacts have [last name],[first name] [middle initial]? It is not clear from your sample.

Comment: There's 1 million total records in uniSelectedContacts. There's a total of 250, for example, in possibles. I want to grab the 250 names of possibles with corresponding address information in uniSelectedContacts. In order to do this, I have to search through a million records. uniSelectedContacts may/may not contain middle initial and possibles may/may not contain middle initial for records that are supposed to match. They may both contain middle initial but one may be full middle name and other may just be middle initial.

Comment: If there's something I can do in excel, perhaps strip middle name from both uniSelectedContacts and possibles, and then keep that as a second table, then I am open to that possibility. So I will have two tables one which search includes middle name but another that doesn't. As long as each query takes under 10 minutes, then it would be a practicals solution.

Comment: Okay, I have added another possibility as it seems that you only have one field for name in uniSelectedContacts.

Comment: Thanks for useful query. Ultimately, I decided to extract middle initials in Excel and create thas as another table. Hence, I have two tables, one with middle and one with out.